# Eliminate Cell Arrays with equal elements

Tags: matlab

In my main script, I am trying to eliminate cell arrays of `S` that have the same elements. For example, if you run the current script (with `a=v=2`) then you will obtain the following values for `S`:

```
S{1}(:, :, 1) = [0 0; 0 0]; S{1}(:, :, 2) = [0 0; 0 0];
S{2}(:, :, 1) = [0 0; 1 1]; S{2}(:, :, 2) = [0 1; 0 1];
S{3}(:, :, 1) = [0 1; 0 1]; S{3}(:, :, 2) = [0 0; 1 1];
S{4}(:, :, 1) = [1 0; 1 0]; S{4}(:, :, 2) = [1 1; 0 0];
S{5}(:, :, 1) = [1 1; 0 0]; S{5}(:, :, 2) = [1 0; 1 0];
S{6}(:, :, 1) = [1 1; 1 1]; S{6}(:, :, 2) = [1 1; 1 1];
```

The code should see `S{2}` and `S{3}`, `S{4}` and `S{5}` as having the same subsets. Therefore, the results I wish to get should be `S{1}`, `S{2}`, `S{4}`, and `S{6}`.

I know MATLAB has the `ismember`, `isequal`, etc. functions but they do not seem to work on cell arrays...or I could not get them working.

Is there a concise way to handle this with cell arrays as it is currently written?

Main Script:

```
clear all
clc

a = 2;
v = 2;

R = dec2base(0:1:v^(v^a)-1, v)-'0';
cnt1 = 0;
cnt2 = 0;

for j=1:v^(v^a)
    % List all degenerates in Psi1 
    V =  FN_Break(a, v, R(j,:));
    if V > 0 % Connector is degenerate
        cnt1 = cnt1 + 1;
        Psi1(cnt1,1) = j-1;
        % Store all "breaks" into cell array S
        S{cnt1} = FN_Break_T(a,v,R(j,:));
    else % Connector is not degenerate
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1;
        Psi2(cnt2,1) = j-1;
    end
end
```

Function `FN_Break`:

```
function [valU] = FN_Beak(a, v, R)

FreeAtomCtr = 0;

for j=0:v^a-1
    for k=1:a
        for l=1:a   
            B =  dec2base(j,v,a);
            atom(l,j+1) = str2num(B(l));
        end
    end
end

for j=1:a % Do this for each atom
    cnt(1:v) = 0;
    for k = 1:v^a  % Do this for each position of each atom
        for l=0:v-1       % Break this down for each value
            if atom(j,k) == l
               cnt(1+l) = cnt(1+l) + 1;
               T(1+l, cnt(1+l),j) = R(k); 
            end
        end
    end
end

for j=1:a
    B = unique(T(:,:,j), 'rows');
    if dot(size(B), [1 0]) < v   % does not depend on this atom
       FreeAtomCtr = FreeAtomCtr + 1;
    end
end

valU = FreeAtomCtr;
end
```

function `FN_Break_T`:

```
function [valU] = FN_Beak_T(a, v, R)

FreeAtomCtr = 0;

for j=0:v^a-1
    for k=1:a
        for l=1:a   
            B =  dec2base(j,v,a);
            atom(l,j+1) = str2num(B(l));
        end
    end
end

for j=1:a % Do this for each atom
    cnt(1:v) = 0;
    for k = 1:v^a  % Do this for each position of each atom
        for l=0:v-1       % Break this down for each value
            if atom(j,k) == l
               cnt(1+l) = cnt(1+l) + 1;
               T(1+l, cnt(1+l),j) = R(k); 
            end
        end
    end
end

for j=1:a
    B = unique(T(:,:,j), 'rows');
    if dot(size(B), [1 0]) < v   % does not depend on this atom
       FreeAtomCtr = FreeAtomCtr + 1;
    end
end

valU = T;
end
```

Comment: Is it intentional that the cells output by your function contain `2 x 2 x 2` arrays?

Comment: Yes. Apologies I was on the "votes" tab and didn't see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to hash your combinations and use those to compare the cell contents. You can use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to index pairs based on possible combinations (4, in this case), then [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the results and use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to find the first instance of each unique (sorted) hash.

For example:

```
S{1}(:, :, 1) = [0 0; 0 0]; S{1}(:, :, 2) = [0 0; 0 0];
S{2}(:, :, 1) = [0 0; 1 1]; S{2}(:, :, 2) = [0 1; 0 1];
S{3}(:, :, 1) = [0 1; 0 1]; S{3}(:, :, 2) = [0 0; 1 1];
S{4}(:, :, 1) = [1 0; 1 0]; S{4}(:, :, 2) = [1 1; 0 0];
S{5}(:, :, 1) = [1 1; 0 0]; S{5}(:, :, 2) = [1 0; 1 0];
S{6}(:, :, 1) = [1 1; 1 1]; S{6}(:, :, 2) = [1 1; 1 1];

combinations = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
% Assume array in every cell has the same shape
hash = zeros(size(S{1}, 1)*size(S{1}, 3), numel(S));
for ii = 1:numel(S)
    [~, hash(:,ii)] = ismember([S{ii}(:, :)].', combinations, 'rows');
end

hash = sort(hash, 1).';
[~, keepidx] = unique(hash, 'rows');
S = S(keepidx);
```

Which gives the desired `S` (cells 1, 2, 4, 6)

---

If you instead want to nest the duplicates, you can use the following:

```
hash = sort(hash, 1).';
[~, keepidx, uniqueidx] = unique(hash, 'rows');
bincounts = accumarray(uniqueidx, 1);  % Count occurrences

for ii = 1:numel(bincounts)
    if bincounts(ii) > 1
        idx = find(uniqueidx == ii);
        S{idx(1)} = S(idx);  % Nest duplicates in first instance of duplicate
    end
end
S = S(keepidx);
```

This uses the third output of `unique` along with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to obtain the occurrence count of each unique combination. The duplicates are nested and then the original cell array is pruned as before.

Comment: I think you edited the S cell array in a way that changed its structure. Not all the items should be separated by semicolons.

Comment: Please see my question above.

Comment: You cannot define 3D arrays in one line. Please answer the question above.

Comment: I have answered your question.

Comment: Fixed question & answer.

Comment: Thank you. One last question - What if I wanted to group them based on the same sub-elements say 1, [2, 3], [4, 5], and 6. Is there is a compact way to do that as you have done above?